# Speeding up left join query

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I have this query which gets me some data from a few tables. The query works perfectly, but it takes the server a long time to get the results.

```
$query_serial       = "SELECT serienummers.serienummer, salesregels.aantalartikelen FROM serienummers
                            LEFT JOIN 
                            (
                                SELECT aantalartikelen, artikelcode, salescode FROM salesregels
                            )salesregels ON salesregels.salescode = serienummers.salescode
                            LEFT JOIN 
                            (
                                SELECT factuurnummer, code FROM sales
                            )sales ON sales.code = serienummers.salescode                            
                            WHERE serienummer = '$serialnumber' AND salesregels.artikelcode = serienummers.artikelcode AND sales.factuurnummer != '-1'
                            ";
```

I've read a few thing online about indexing the tables, but im not quite sure how to apply this. Could anyone point me in the right direction, please?

My tables:

```
Serienummers:
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| serienummer   | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |       |
| artikelcode   | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| datum         | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| usercode      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| salescode     | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| reparatiecode | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| actie         | varchar(250) | NO   |     |         |       |
| rmacode       | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
Salesregels
+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-
-----+-----+-----------+-------+
| Field                     | Type                                            |
Null | Key | Default   | Extra |
+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-
-----+-----+-----------+-------+
| code                      | int(11)                                         |
NO   | PRI | 0         |       |
| salescode                 | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| aantalartikelen           | double                                          |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| artikelcode               | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| prijsperstukinclbtw_old   | varchar(20)                                     |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| btwtypecode               | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| artikeltekst              | varchar(250)                                    |
NO   |     |           |       |
| procentbtw_old            | varchar(10)                                     |
NO   |     | 0,00      |       |
| isprijsonderdrukt         | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| volgordenummer            | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| prijsperstukinclbtw       | double                                          |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| procentbtw                | double                                          |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| korting                   | double                                          |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| kortingtype               | enum('procenten','eurosinclbtw','eurosexclbtw') |
NO   |     | procenten |       |
| inkoopprijsperstukexclbtw | double                                          |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| inkoopprijsprocentbtw     | double                                          |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| inkoopprijsbtwtypecode    | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
| dagengarantie             | int(11)                                         |
NO   |     | 0         |       |
+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-
Sales
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code                    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| salestypecode           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| websitesalesidcode      | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| datum                   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| datumbetaald            | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| datumlaatstgewijzigd    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| usercodelaatstgewijzigd | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| adrescode               | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| usercode                | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| bedragvoldaan1_old      | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| bedragvoldaan1          | double       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| betalingswijzecode1     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| bedragvoldaan2_old      | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| bedragvoldaan2          | double       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| betalingswijzecode2     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| opmerkingen             | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| opmerkingenextern       | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| voorraadlokatiecode     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| computernaam            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| factuurnummer           | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| betaald                 | int(11)      | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| status                  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dagenbetalingstermijn   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 8       |       |
| externordernummer       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| externfactuurnummer     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| isdeleted               | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Try running MySQL `EXPLAIN` on your query. Also, at the very least, try creating indexes on the `salescode`/`code` fields on which you are performing the JOINS.

Comment: Some helpful links: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html you can also possibly look into `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Do you really need `LEFT`?  It somewhat restricts the optimizer to start with the left table; it might be better to start with the right table.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need selecting everything using inner query before doing the `join`.
The joins could be done directly.

```
select
sr.serienummer,
sg.aantalartikelen
from serienummers sr
left join salesregels sg on sg.salescode = sr.salescode and sg.artikelcode = sr.artikelcode
left join sales s on s.code = sr.salescode
where 
sr.serienummer = '$serialnumber'
and s.factuurnummer != '-1' ;
```

Now to speed up you need indexes on the joining keys and keys used in where clause.

```
alter table serienummers add index sales_kel_code(salescode,artikelcode);
alter table serienummers add index serienummer_idx(serienummer);
alter table salesregels add index salescode_idx(salescode);
alter table sales add index factuurnummer_idx(factuurnummer);
```

Comment: If you are using WHERE in a LEFT JOIN you might as well turn it into an INNER.JOIN.

Comment: Right left join with where is nothing but inner join so better would be use inner join.